# How to display all result from JLabel to JFrame

Tags: java, swing

I have a problem with displaying all the labels contained in the loop. In the provided code, he receives only the last query result. It seems to me that the rest is covered. Any ideas ?

```
public static void ViewTable(Connection con) throws SQLException {
    java.sql.Statement stmt = null;
    JFrame submenu = new JFrame("View");
    submenu.setSize(500, 500);
    submenu.setVisible(true);
    JLabel text = new JLabel("Lista przystankow: ");
    submenu.add(text, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    String query = "SELECT * FROM Stacja";
    try {
        stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
        while (rs.next()) {
            String idStacja = rs.getString("idStacja");
            String nazwa = rs.getString("nazwa");
            JLabel input = new JLabel(" " + idStacja + " " + nazwa);
            submenu.add(input, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            System.out.println(" " + idStacja + " " + nazwa);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...receives only the last query result

Because you fill the JLabel in the while loop, with the same variable, instead you can use a global variable to combine all the results, then show the it in the end, you can use `StringBuilder` for example :

```
StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder();
while (rs.next()) {
    message.append(space)
        .append(rs.getString("idStacja"))
        .append(" ")
        .append(rs.getString("nazwa"))
        .append(" ");
}
JLabel input = new JLabel(message.toString());
submenu.add(input, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Answer (score 0):

You put all in the CENTER of the panel. I recommend adding another panel having e.g. FlowLayout:

```
public static void ViewTable(Connection con) throws SQLException {
    java.sql.Statement stmt = null;
    JFrame submenu = new JFrame("View");
    submenu.setSize(500, 500);
    submenu.setVisible(true);
    JLabel text = new JLabel("Lista przystankow: ");
    submenu.add(text, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    String query = "SELECT * FROM Stacja";
    JPanel labelpanel = new JPanel();
    labelpanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    try {
       stmt = con.createStatement();
       ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
       while (rs.next()) {
            String idStacja = rs.getString("idStacja");
            String nazwa = rs.getString("nazwa");              
            labelpanel.add( new JLabel(" " + idStacja + " " + nazwa));
            System.out.println(" " + idStacja + " " + nazwa);
        }
        submenu.add(labelpanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Probably the FlowLayout is not the thing you expect. There are other possiblities, e.g. GridBagLayout that gives you much more possibilities in positionning the components.